# Listing Elements of a jSON file in Table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I want to list all the elements in this jSON file in a Table View

```
{
   "GetBuildingsRadiusJsonResult":[
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5001402005001",
         "DISTANCIA":21.32146784390920,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73580937270080,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15660678323934,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 20-20B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5001402008001",
         "DISTANCIA":34.53373314061230,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73569047355290,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15607623644036,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 14"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201021001",
         "DISTANCIA":29.13207744582850,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73539981163320,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15636893767009,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 31-31A"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201023001",
         "DISTANCIA":34.608510460067,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73552941823310,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15683701485913,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 39-39E"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201027001",
         "DISTANCIA":24.92522103436050,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73542668844180,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15649968147357,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 33-33B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201029001",
         "DISTANCIA":28.14768277223310,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.735470995147,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15669924136460,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 37-37B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201028001",
         "DISTANCIA":25.19034723079050,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73544762568370,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15660101384062,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 35-35B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5000201033001",
         "DISTANCIA":36.53199372687960,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73537439211060,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15624045741059,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 29-29B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5001402004001",
         "DISTANCIA":13.64427058972170,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73576229086240,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15640626273806,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 18-18B"
      },
      {
         "COD_SIG":"5001402012001",
         "DISTANCIA":23.90756953606770,
         "IDTIPO":"2",
         "LATITUDE":38.73573141844790,
         "LONGITUDE":-9.15621547369463,
         "MORADA":"Rua Ramalho Ortigão, 16-16A"
      }
   ]
}
```

And i want the name of each row to be the "COD_SIG" value.

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface lxvProcessesViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *processTableView;

    NSArray *processes;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@end
```

and .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    processTableView.delegate = self;
    processTableView.dataSource = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lxi.cm-lisboa.pt/wsgeospatialops2/geospatialopsrest.svc/GetBuildingsRadiusjson?longitude=-9.15647&latitude=38.73565&nResults=10"];
    NSURL *urlTenBuildings = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

    NSLog(@"URL --------  %@  ---------",str);

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlTenBuildings];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Entrou no viewDidLoad");

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Entrou no connection didReceiveResponse");
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    NSLog(@"Entrou no connection didReceiveData");
    [data appendData:theData];

    NSString* txt = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSLog(@"Resultado do URL  ------ %@ -------", txt);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Entrou no connectionDidFinishLoading");

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    processes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    [processTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Entrou no connection didFailWithError");
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"O acesso não foi completado. Verifique que está ligado à Internet via 3G ou Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}

-(long) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(long)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[processes count]);

    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Entrou no tableView");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Main Cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Main Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[processes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COD_SIG"];

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);

    return  cell;
}
```

I get an error at this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[processes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COD_SIG"];
```

Here is the console error: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: -1 for not bothering to list the exact error message.

Comment: (Of course, we all know the error was something like `[NSDictionary objectAtIndex:] object does not respond to selector`.)

Comment: @HotLicks : OP is new at SO website... such errors are obvious... I don't think this is reason for DOWNVOTE. We should help him... Just my view...

Comment: @FahimParkar - The downvote will help him remember next time.  (And, more importantly, he needs to learn that error messages contain valuable information.  Had he studied the error message and tried to figure it out he might have solved this on his own.)

Comment: @FahimParkar: One of the points of downvotes is to mark the question as unlikely to be helpful to future readers. Without a specific description of the problem -- i.e., the error message, that's precisely the case here. Even if another person has exactly the same problem, they wouldn't be able to tell because there's not enough information in the question.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't specified the error because I thought it was irrelevant and the only thing wrong with the code was on that specific line (once it was the line where the app crashed). So I'm very sorry to not bother.

Comment: **THE ERROR MESSAGE TELLS YOU EXACTLY WHAT'S WRONG!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root element in the JSON is a dictionary, not an array.

Replace

```
processes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

with

```
processes = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] objectForKey:@"GetBuildingsRadiusJsonResult"];
```

to get the array from the JSON.

And modify numberOfRowsInSection to return

```
return [processes count];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting error because of wrong return number_of_rows in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
-(long)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[processes count]);

    return 10;
}
```

should be

```
-(long)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[processes count]);

    return [processes count];
}
```

Also replace,

```
processes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

with

```
processes = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] objectForKey:@"GetBuildingsRadiusJsonResult"];
```

as you have data as NSDictionary and not NSArray.

Comment: I used `return 10;` because I was sure of the number of rows I needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your dictionary contains array and then that array again contains the dictionaries. So first you need to parse the dictionary and then you need to parse the array.
Try like this :-

```
   cell.textLabel.text = [[[processes objectForKey:GetBuildingsRadiusJsonResult] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COD_SIG"];
```

Comment: this worked on another part of the code I wasn't getting right either, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
cell.textLabel.text = processes[@"GetBuildingsRadiusJsonResult"][indexPath.row][@"COD_SIG"]
```

Forgot to mention that processes should be a dictionary and not an array